# how to work with playerprefs in a character selection menu in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a character selection menu in which you should have enough coins to buy (unlock) characters. Once one of the characters is selected, your coins must be decreased according to it's price and when you restart the game and that character is selected again, it must not be locked and your coins must not be decreased either. I tried different ways but none of them worked. I accidentally came to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G_I6GxGIB_Y) video. here is my script;

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using UnityEditor;
 public class MainMenu3 : MonoBehaviour {
 int SceneIndex;

     public Button BluePlane;
     public Button WhitePlane;

     public GameObject wood;
     public static int character_number;
     public int isPlanesold;


     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         isPlanesold = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("isPlanesold");
         if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("Number")) {
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Number", 1);
         }
                 character_number = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Number");
         UIManager2.coin_score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Score");
             SceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().buildIndex;
     }

     public void Blueplane () {
         character_number = 1;
         SceneManager.LoadScene ("Menu2");
     }

     public void BuyWhitePlane () {
         if (UIManager2.coin_score >= 1 && isPlanesold ==0) {
             WhitePlane.interactable = true;
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("isPlanesold", 1);
             character_number = 2;
             UIManager2.coin_score--;
             wood.SetActive (false);
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Score", UIManager2.coin_score);
             PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Number", character_number);
             SceneManager.LoadScene ("Menu2");
         }
         else
             WhitePlane.interactable = false;
     }

         void Update () {
         if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Escape))
             SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneIndex - 1);
         }
```

when for example I earn 1 coin by BluePlane that's already unlocked by default and click on WhitePlane button, it works fine but when I restart the game, the button returns to WhitePlane.interactable = false; I know what should I do but I really don't know how!

Comment: Where is Score in `PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Score")` initialized?

Comment: My game is like flappybird in which for every n score, your coin number (coin_score) must be increased for 1 unit. coin_score is a static int variable to be put on a TEXT UI and appears in play scene (top-left).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok from what I can see you have 2 problems.

Firstly, you're not giving `isPlanesold`a default value. When you get a `PlayerPref` for the first time you assign it a default value incase no value for it currently exists.

Secondly, I think its because you don't have an 'already unlocked' option for BuyWhitePlane, only 'not unlocked' and 'can't unlock'. If `isPlaneSold`gets set to 1 (like it does when you buy the plane) you can't select the WhitePlane again (ie, when you reload the game).

Also I would call `PlayerPrefs.Save()` after the user makes a purchase incase the game exits prematurely or crashes, this way the user will keep their progress.

Therefore, I think your script should look something like this:

```
public class MainMenu3 : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Button BluePlane;
    [SerializeField] Button WhitePlane;
    [SerializeField] GameObject wood;

    int character_number;
    int isPlanesold;
    int score;

    void Start() 
    {
        isPlanesold = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("isPlanesold", 0); // I guess you're using this like a true/false? So the plane won't to be sold at first, so it would be zero. Could also convert to a bool with Convert.ToBoolean()
        character_number = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Number", 1);
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score", 0); 
    }

    public void Blueplane()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Number", 1);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu2");
    }

    public void BuyWhitePlane()
    {
        if (isPlaneSold == 1)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Number", 2);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu2");
        }

        else if (score >= 1 && isPlanesold == 0)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isPlanesold", 1);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Number", 2);
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score--);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            // wood.SetActive(false); If you're immediately changing scenes, whats the point in doing this? 
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Menu2");
        }

        else
        {
            Debug.Log("You don't have the score!");
            // Do stuff, maybe an UI error message? 
            // If you wanted to make the button not intractable if the user didn't have the score you could check the score value in start and if it was 0 set WhileButton.intractable = false;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex - 1);
    }
```

If you're planning to add more planes and `isPlaneSold`'s value will increase past 1 then I would recommend adding a method to you don't end up repeating the same

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isPlanesold", 1);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Number", 2);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", score--);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

code.

On a side note, using `PlayerPrefs` to store information like this (ie the users unlocks and coins) is bad because a `PlayerPref`'s data is in an insecure fire somewhere in the users device. It should only be used to store stuff that the user can already freely (such as settings). A better solution would be to use `BinaryFormatter`, I would recommend [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XOjd_qU2Ido) video to learn how to use them.

Furthermore, I can't see the rest of your code so I can't be sure but as you're saving `UIManager2.coinscore` and `character_number`in `PlayerPrefs`they don't need to be static? Static variables can cause some strange behaviour if you don't know what you're doing, and as a rough guideline [should be avoided](http://www.41post.com/3424/programming/using-static-variables-in-unity3d).

Hope this helps and best of luck!

Comment: Thanks a million! You saved my life! God bless you! I used character_number as a static variable, because it must be referenced on another scene. and for Gameobject (wood) because it acts as a lock, once player buy that character, it must not be shown anymore. for wood.SetActive (false) to be saved I defined a boolean variable, named it (iswoodunlocked) and set it as wood.SetActive (iswoodunlocked) in start () but it didn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: @amin007 What you could do for your `wood` variable is create another `PlayerPref` (something like `PlayersPrefs.GetString("isWoodUnlocked", "false")`, set it to `true` when the user buys a plane and then check `if (PlayersPrefs.GetString("isWoodUnlocked") == "true")` in `Start()`. As for the static variable I was just a little confused because you could just check `PlayerPref.GetInt("Number")` in your next scene instead of using a static. Anyway, glad I could help :)

Comment: Stupid me! Thanks bro! I am new to unity! But one more thing! When I set another plane, if for number of coins was 2 and I first bought the first plane (coins for 1), and number of my coins decreased as schedule. But when I collected enough coins to buy the next plane and bought that, the coins number didn't change. I guess coin_score must have defined for plane number 1. as you said maybe I should use another method for next planes

Comment: @amin007 No problem man, everyone starts at the beginning. I don't quite understand what you mean. If you're referring to the number of coins you can see in your game you might be forgetting to actually update the value when you buy a new plane (ie, if you have some text telling the user how many coins they have you could be forgetting to change this). Else, remember to change the value of coins in your `PlayerPref`, something like `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", currentCoins - planeCost)`. Best of luck man!